# Should I apply the other job in the same company just right after final interview?

Tags: interviewing, recruitment

I had a job interview at company "A" through a headhunter. After spending almost 2 months there, 2 weeks ago I arrived at the final round of interviews.
I haven't heard anything back from the company. I emailed the headhunter but she just ignored my email and keeps silence.

I assume that I am not getting this job. I discovered that the company has an opening for other department. Should I apply that job now?

My Questions are:

1. Is this too early to apply the other job at the same company?
   I'm worried that there is a possibility I meet the same HR person whom I met 3 weeks ago even though it's different department.
2. I applied the job through the head hunter as I mentioned; will it be a problem if I apply to other job not through her? I don't know if there is a rule about working with headhunter. I was thinking to ask the headhunter to help me applying for other job, but she hasn't even following up my previous interview 
   so I wouldn't work with her again.

Answer (score 3):

> Is this too early to apply other job at the same company?

No, it's never really too early as long as you haven't received a verbal offer. Just be clear when applying that you are already in the interview process with Manager X in Department B.

> I applied the job through the head hunter as I mentioned, it will be a problem if I apply other job not through her?

First, check your contract with your recruiter. If you signed something agreeing that your recruiter is the only person who can represent you to this company, then yes, you need to go through her. **If you break an agreement there could be legal repercussions, so you must be certain of this.** *(IANAL)* If you don't have any sort of agreement like this things are a lot muddier. You would be technically allowed to not use this recruiter, but you can expect that she will call you unprofessional and never work with you again. This is very bad if you are still waiting to hear from the first job.

My recommendation is that if you are okay to (or required to) go through the recruiter for the second job, then go ahead and ask her about it. If you plan to apply directly instead, then wait until you have word back for the first job before you cut ties with your recruiter.